# How can i reduce state management dependencies in my package?

Tags: flutter, dart, package

I am developing the [widgetbook](https://pub.dev/packages/widgetbook) package, which is a storybook for flutter. A few of the early users criticised that the package uses too many dependencies (especially `bloc` and `flutter_bloc`) which makes it hard to use if an older version of one of the dependencies is required by the project.

**The problem**

I agree with the feedback of our users and *I would like to reduce the amount of dependencies*. Unfortunately, i don't know how i can conveniently replace the state management solution without increasing development effort on my side.

**I see the following options**

1. Replace `bloc` by `provider`. But this doesn't really solve anything. It just uses a state management solution which is even more frequently used.
2. Copy the code from e.g. `bloc` or `provider` and include the code in my package. This eliminates the dependency, but introduces several negative trade offs: increased package size, redundancy, maintainability, and i don't like "stealing" the code.
3. Replace `bloc` with `InheritedWidget`. `InheritedWidget` is a state management solution provided by the flutter SDK. But using it is cumbersome and therefore needs additional development for easier use. I feel like putting additional development into making `InheritedWidget` more accessible would likely result in something that `provider` already implements. Therefore, I'd reinvent the weel which basically leads to *option 2*.
4. `setState`. This is pretty much similar to the argumentation of *option 3*.

**In summary**

I feel like using a self-implemented state management solution takes a lot of time reinventing the weel, but I see no other way of eliminating the dependency.

Am I missing any options?

Comment: Everyone uses provider (flutter bloc does under the hood for example) so it seems like a far trade of. Using InheritedWidget is honestly not that bad once you learn how to use it. It depends on the size of your package of course but if you really want to remove dependencies this is definitely the best option. Depends on how much of your time/effort you want to invest really ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is your decision ultimately and I think an answer here might not convince you any other way. It is indeed your time and effort.

Here is my insight on all options,

1. Yes, it doesn't solve anything. Might I suggest a state management solution used by less users, here is [Turbo](https://pub.dev/packages/turbo), that I wrote to eliminate pointless complex abstractions (eg. GetX), pretentious principles (eg. Bloc), contextifying & complicating things (eg. Provider)... It even has one of the simplest event systems. But still, this also is not be a great option as it increases development time and effort, since you have to learn it. Also in the end, Turbo is not used by many people.
2. This is essentially suicidal, especially if you are going to go with `Bloc`. You should be able to maintain your own package, that is if you want to. By cloning another codebase into your own, you are bringing in technical debt. This also increases development time, for now and also for the future.

**Unless you created a new programming language and are using the same language for development, every piece of code you write is "stolen" from somewhere. Besides creating a new language, only logic can be original, code can never be.**

3. Like you said cumbersome. And also increases development time. You are reinventing the wheel. Which is unnecessary in most cases.
4. `setState` - This increases development time and also might increase the clutter in your codebase. But to be honest. This is what everyone uses, not Provider. This is what everyone knows. Also if your user base is complaining about depending upon a state management solution, this is technically your only option. If your user base is worried about many dependencies, I still recommend **Turbo**. It is that simple and will at least get rid of `bloc` and `flutter_bloc`.

In all options, there seems to be a need for increased development effort, which you said you don't want. So I suggest that you either make peace with the option that you are comfortable with, or hire someone else to do the refactoring for you. I recommend the latter, since I don't know your personal preference.

Comment: I know that the post is old and the answer might be irrelevant, but it is somewhat meant to be sarcasm and also might be helpful for someone seeing the question.